# Change the color of x SVG files

Tags: regex, string, loops, svg, colors

I'd like to change the color of at least 1.000 SVG files. The main problem I have is that the currently SVGs doesnt contain the "fill" attribute, so I have to add fill="X" at the end of the SVG tag.

Heres is an example of one SVG file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" " x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="-236 286 30 30" style="enable-background:new -236 286 30 30;" xml:space="preserve">
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you provide more information? Did you already try some regex? How should the result look like?

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer.

The result should be look like this:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" " x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="-236 286 30 30" style="enable-background:new -236 286 30 30;" xml:space="preserve" **fill="red"** >

Comment: do you know the website https://regex101.com? I use that page constantly when working with regex.

Comment: How do you plan to use the svg elements? In the case you are using inline svg you can set the fill in css like `svg{fill:red}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many possibilites to do that. The safest way would be to read the XML structure and then manipulate that. But for that specific example you could also use the following regex with e.g. sed or python:

With sed:

```sh
sed -E 's/xml:space=\"preserve\">/xml:space="preserve" fill="red" >/gm;t;d'
```

With Python:

```py
import re

regex = r"xml:space=\"preserve\">"

test_str = ("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
    "<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->\n"
    "<svg version=\"1.1\" id=\"Layer_1\" \" x=\"0px\" y=\"0px\"\n"
    "     viewBox=\"-236 286 30 30\" style=\"enable-background:new -236 286 30 30;\" xml:space=\"preserve\">")

subst = "xml:space=\"preserve\" fill=\"red\" >"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)
```

you can also have a look at [regex101.com/r/cIfbEd](https://regex101.com/r/cIfbEd)

Comment: I did in another way. I used BBEdit to find the mentioned string and replaced it with my wished color attribute. Thanks for your kick in the right direction. :)